# post_max_size AND upload_max_filesize max value

Tags: max, php

I want to increase max_post_size AND upload_max_filesize but when I enter 9.9G it work but when I enter 10G or 1T My Script doesn't work. Can I enter 10G or more value in max_post_size AND upload_max_filesize ??? what is max value ???